# After Lily and Severus had their 5th year argument, did she still retain SOME romantic love?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, lily-potter

We know that
Lily and Snape were great friends at a young age, and that Snape loved her dearly, so far as to match her Patronus and become a double agent after her death. However, we know of their falling out as well. Did she return his affections, at least a little, even after their argument? Note: I am referring to the argument in front of the portrait hole, the one in which Snape threatened to sleep outside.

(Please no answers from HP Wiki/Wikia, Lexicon, or movie quotes, however, canon-based examples, book quotes, JKR tweets, Pottermore, and interviews are fine. If you have canon-based speculation please leave a comment! I love to read speculations!)

Comment: question presumes she had romatic love in the first place

Comment: @NKCampbell i remember reading from some sort of JKR interview that she did...could be wrong though :)